# Using of a single view to display different content on flip

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add a flip on row did select of every section.The flip side view should display the content of the selected section. I have tried to understand the apple transition tutorial but its tough to get.
Any simple application related to it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Apple Sample code? That is pretty well laid out and has a flip animation. If you create a default utility project, that code has pretty much nothing but flip code in it.

Generating a flip animation is very easy. You simply remove your main view (in your case the UITableView) and add your new view to the superView all inside a UIView animation block:

```
// start the animation block [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

// Specify a flip transition
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
[myAppsWindow removeSubView:myUITableView]; // obiously replace these views with the correct views from your app.
[myAppsWindow addSubview:mybackView];  // you should build this view with your details in it.    
// commit the animations. The animations will run when this invocation of the runloop returns. 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```